# Add nearest coordinates values from one file to another file in R

Tags: r

I have 2 files `df1` and `df2`. File `df1` has `lat` and `lon`, file `df2` has `lat`, `lon` and `wind`. `df1` and `df2` files have different `lat`, `lon`.

Now I want to add `df2$value2` in the file `df2` corresponding to the nearest `lat` and `lon` coordinates of `df1` file.

So `df1` file would become like:

```
lat    lon     wind
30.037 80.572 "some value"
```

please provide some information in that.

`df1` file is:

```
lat     lon
30.037  80.572
23.671  85.008
22.791  86.206
23.755  86.421
23.673  86.088
23.768  86.392
23.789  86.243
23.805  86.327
23.682  86.085
23.68   86.095
21.194  81.41
16.95   81.912
16.952  81.898
16.899  81.682
12.994  79.651
9.2 77.603
12.291  77.346
17.996  79.708
17.998  79.718
16.61   81.266
16.499  81.2
19.505  81.784
18.322  80.555
19.506  81.794
21.081  81.957
21.223  82.127
20.918  81.025
19.861  82.123
20.62   75.049
21.222  82.116
21.608  82.338
21.61   82.349
21.655  84.081
21.733  81.195
21.819  81.84
21.879  82.941
21.731  81.185
21.122  75.809
21.218  76.557
22.931  77.455
22.843  77.541
22.863  78.898
22.865  78.907
22.509  78.014
22.797  86.204
22.966  77.269
24.201  82.714
23.395  79.717
24.148  82.617
28.97   77.428
27.017  78.44
27.343  80.791
25.525  75.636
29.051  78.111
27.942  79.886
27.748  79.197
27.475  79.347
27.365  80.038
27.977  80.812
27.747  79.187
28.088  78.201
28.984  78.087
28.221  79.156
27.936  78.827
28.068  78.521
28.976  78.099
28.291  77.638
28.077  78.059
28.272  78.134
28.929  78.031
28.29   77.628
28.461  77.791
31.102  77.904
31.101  77.893
31.104  77.914
31.761  76.649
31.063  78.018
30.812  78.466
30.659  78.019
30.663  78.317
30.604  78.496
29.403  77.487
29.997  76.889
29.531  78.65
29.027  77.563
29.061  77.351
29.033  77.604
29.012  77.587
29.101  77.688
29.103  77.698
29.074  77.825
29.076  77.835
29.057  77.578
29.241  78.951
28.992  77.203
29.103  77.511
29.66   79.697
28.998  76.334
29.175  77.758
29  76.345
29.164  77.43
29.155  77.432
29.181  77.542
29.332  77.438
29.303  77.365
29.273  77.35
29.184  77.374
29.237  77.483
29.349  77.56
29.398  77.394
29.401  77.477
29.67   79.277
29.415  77.506
29.574  77.971
29.455  77.271
29.449  77.419
29.64   77.527
29.906  79.683
29.543  77.248
28.255  97.043
28.192  97.064
28.256  97.052
14.045  75.67
16.56   74.755
16.368  75.517
16.37   75.528
15.954  75.028
17.194  74.213
17.499  74.089
23.681  86.096
23.682  86.086
23.771  86.401
22.33   82.669
28.186  97.063
25.758  94.841
24.748  94.051
24.759  94.035
30.86   78.628
30.804  78.505
31.203  78.237
30.665  78.318
30.426  78.063
28.583  80.455
25.971  76.999
28.139  80.48
24.733  78.11
24.145  82.617
24.199  82.722
23.418  79.289
23.69   79.46
22.321  69.88
22.322  69.887
22.324  69.867
21.254  76.657
18.547  74.569
21.379  74.723
18.549  74.559
19.026  73.457
21.584  72.944
18.429  74.69
18.427  74.699
17.983  74.964
17.756  75.316
17.747  75.314
17.755  75.325
17.746  75.324
17.024  77.158
12.94   76.346
14.03   75.442
14.039  75.443
12.741  76.376
12.152  76.847
12.349  76.579
22.789  86.213
23.362  91.398
27.137  95.573
27.903  96.198
27.876  96.331
27.136  95.561
28.169  97.031
28.18   97.031
25.379  94.2
25.297  92.62
25.493  92.633
25.267  92.731
24.814  94.032
23.88   91.35
25.764  94.834
25.762  94.823
25.754  94.835
25.544  93.922
25.545  93.932
26.081  94.447
26  94.237
26.082  94.457
26.038  94.383
26.922  94.412
27.091  95.523
26.575  94.909
26.081  94.371
26.126  94.429
27.093  95.535
27.066  95.564
27.067  95.576
26.741  94.657
26.945  94.442
26.723  95.095
26.711  94.69
26.712  94.701
27.081  95.524
26.875  95.256
26.949  95.701
27.083  95.536
26.885  95.255
17.256  73.805
14.458  75.149
14.382  75.179
14.384  75.194
17.797  75.468
18.522  74.372
19.471  74.682
19.867  73.77
22.093  74.895
23.238  70.078
21.657  71.634
22.326  69.735
22.091  74.876
23.77   86.394
22.335  82.664
23.795  86.242
26.738  95.19
26.74   95.178
26.926  94.4
26.919  95.396
27.462  95.472
26.604  94.841
26.73   95.176
26.731  95.183
26.733  95.171
26.728  95.188
26.725  95.201
26.606  94.827
26.59   95.038
26.592  95.026
26.58   95.036
26.582  95.023
26.464  94.993
26.598  94.818
26.605  94.835
26.472  95.008
26.595  94.833
26.593  94.846
26.75   93.437
26.585  94.831
26.462  95.007
24.847  94.039
24.903  94.018
22.064  88.126
23.765  86.394
23.794  86.242
22.792  86.204
22.797  86.211
17.649  82.549
18.028  83.305
26.571  95.016
26.554  95.022
26.567  95.023
26.573  94.795
26.581  94.829
27.169  95.636
26.583  94.826
26.575  94.789
27.049  95.554
26.601  94.824
27.043  95.565
27.003  95.54
27.161  95.636
20.811  70.696
21.028  70.314
16.92   81.579
16.921  81.589
17.639  82.551
17.025  81.661
18.925  84.451
17.648  82.55
21.145  79.257
21.036  80.534
21.034  80.523
20.915  81.705
20.793  81.214
20.935  82.53
20.75   81.538
19.24   73.212
18.247  73.233
19.224  73.215
19.234  73.217
22.789  86.208
21.896  81.738
21.898  81.748
21.965  83.226
21.916  83.008
24.144  82.749
24.144  82.619
23.502  79.217
23.449  83.977
23.504  79.229
23.677  80.883
22.541  78.06
22.905  79.4
22.907  79.412
23.788  86.241
24.205  82.723
26.734  91.051
25.339  83.562
25.345  83.604
24.203  82.713
26.729  91.047
27.489  79.98
27.335  82.211
27.055  82.58
26.618  81.432
26.616  81.422
27.411  84.093
27.142  82.476
27.14   82.465
27.548  80.001
29.693  78.041
29.08   78.697
29.423  78.646
30.167  78.96
16.85   74.487
14.49   75.963
14.016  75.685
14.488  75.954
16.777  74.678
16.05   75.423
14.553  75.957
16.553  74.653
16.024  74.937
16.328  75.683
16.278  75.345
16.326  75.674
16.28   75.354
19.012  76.563
18.129  74.156
21.482  76.479
23.774  86.394
23.796  86.245
24.204  82.718
27.454  80.675
24.148  82.755
21.237  82.138
22.331  82.669
22.951  78.939
24.232  77.153
18.949  78.514
19.235  77.355
20.101  80.64
20.003  81.531
19.246  76.203
18.647  74.71
17.715  81.883
18.056  75.023
17.454  78.463
18.022  75.128
16.27   75.476
16.669  73.538
17.324  74.061
16.582  74.994
16.028  79.044
14.129  75.848
```

`df2` file is:

```
lat     lon     wind
26.625  82.375  2.8404799746488
26.625  82.5    2.84172641360288
26.625  82.625  2.83466325952975
26.625  82.75   2.8278078452823
26.625  82.875  2.82074469120916
26.625  83  2.81388927696171
26.625  83.125  2.80682612288857
26.625  83.25   2.79997070864112
26.625  83.375  2.74118033797356
26.625  83.5    2.68259770713168
26.625  83.625  2.62380733646412
26.625  83.75   2.56522470562224
26.625  83.875  2.50664207478037
26.625  84  2.44785170411281
26.625  84.125  2.39134647152773
26.625  84.25   2.33484123894266
26.625  84.375  2.27854374618326
26.625  84.5    2.22203851359819
26.625  84.625  2.16553328101311
26.625  84.75   2.10923578825372
26.625  84.875  2.05356151497137
26.625  85  1.9980949815147
26.625  85.125  1.94242070823234
26.625  85.25   1.88674643494999
26.625  85.375  1.83107216166764
26.625  85.5    1.77539788838528
26.625  85.625  1.75711678372541
26.625  85.75   1.73862793923985
26.625  85.875  1.72013909475429
26.625  86  1.70165025026874
26.625  86.125  1.68336914560886
26.625  86.25   1.6648803011233
26.625  86.375  1.61917753947361
26.625  86.5    1.57347477782392
26.625  86.625  1.5279797559999
26.625  86.75   1.48227699435021
26.625  86.875  1.43657423270052
26.625  87  1.39087147105083
26.625  87.125  1.32709534456694
26.625  87.25   1.26331921808305
26.625  87.375  1.19933535177348
26.625  87.5    1.13555922528959
26.625  87.625  1.07157535898002
26.625  87.75   1.00779923249613
26.625  87.875  0.982454973763119
26.625  88  0.957318454855788
26.625  88.125  0.931974196122777
26.625  88.25   0.906629937389766
26.625  88.375  0.881493418482434
26.625  88.5    0.856149159749424
26.625  88.625  0.865497451905043
26.625  88.75   0.874638004234981
26.625  88.875  0.883778556564919
26.625  89  0.893126848720538
26.625  89.125  0.902267401050476
26.625  89.25   0.911615693206096
26.625  89.375  0.925326521701003
26.625  89.5    0.939037350195911
26.625  89.625  0.952748178690819
26.625  89.75   0.966459007185727
26.625  89.875  0.980377575506315
26.625  90  0.993880664175542
26.625  90.125  0.999905119120275
26.625  90.25   1.00551409441365
26.625  90.375  1.0113308095327
26.625  90.5    1.01714752465175
26.625  90.625  1.02275649994512
26.625  90.75   1.02857321506417
26.625  90.875  1.05973418891624
26.625  91  1.09110290259398
26.625  91.125  1.12205613662036
26.625  91.25   1.15342485029811
26.625  91.375  1.18458582415017
26.625  91.5    1.21595453782791
26.625  91.625  1.27142107128458
26.625  91.75   1.32709534456694
26.625  91.875  1.38256187802361
26.625  92  1.43823615130596
26.625  92.125  1.49391042458831
26.625  92.25   1.54937695804499
26.625  92.375  1.55997168915469
26.625  92.5    1.57077416009007
26.625  92.625  1.58136889119977
26.625  92.75   1.59196362230947
26.625  92.875  1.60276609324486
26.625  93  1.61336082435456
26.625  93.125  1.5832385496309
26.625  93.25   1.55311627490724
26.625  93.375  1.52320174000925
26.625  93.5    1.49307946528559
26.625  93.625  1.46295719056193
26.625  93.75   1.43304265566395
26.625  93.875  1.418708607692
26.625  94  1.40479003937141
26.625  94.125  1.39066373122515
26.625  94.25   1.37653742307888
26.625  94.375  1.36241111493261
26.625  94.5    1.34828480678634
26.625  94.625  1.31338451607203
26.625  94.75   1.27848422535772
26.625  94.875  1.24358393464341
26.625  95  1.2086836439291
26.625  95.125  1.17357561338911
26.625  95.25   1.1386753226748
26.625  95.375  1.20141275003028
26.625  95.5    1.26415017738577
26.625  95.625  1.32709534456694
26.625  95.75   1.38983277192242
26.625  95.875  1.45277793910359
26.625  96  1.51551536645908
26.625  96.125  1.5078289929089
26.625  96.25   1.49993487953305
26.625  96.375  1.49224850598287
26.625  96.5    1.4845621324327
26.625  96.625  1.47687575888252
26.625  96.75   1.46898164550666
26.625  96.875  1.49806522110192
26.625  97  1.52714879669718
26.625  97.125  1.55623237229244
26.625  97.25   1.5853159478877
26.625  97.375  1.61439952348296
26.625  97.5    1.64348309907822
26.625  97.625  1.61917753947361
26.625  97.75   1.594871979869
26.625  97.875  1.57056642026439
26.625  98  1.5460531208341
26.625  98.125  1.52174756122949
26.625  98.25   1.49744200162488
26.625  98.375  1.48206925452453
26.625  98.5    1.46669650742418
26.625  98.625  1.45132376032383
26.625  98.75   1.43595101322348
26.625  98.875  1.42057826612313
26.625  99  1.40520551902278
26.625  99.125  1.44363738677365
26.625  99.25   1.48227699435021
26.625  99.375  1.52070886210109
26.625  99.5    1.55934846967765
26.625  99.625  1.59778033742853
26.625  99.75   1.63641994500508
26.625  99.875  1.6266561731981
26.625  100 1.61668466156544
26.5    60  2.18339890602163
26.5    60.125  2.20625028684648
26.5    60.25   2.22910166767132
26.5    60.375  2.25195304849617
26.5    60.5    2.27480442932102
26.5    60.625  2.29765581014586
26.5    60.75   2.32050719097071
26.5    60.875  2.43289443666382
26.5    61  2.5454894221826
26.5    61.125  2.65787666787571
26.5    61.25   2.7704716533945
26.5    61.375  2.88306663891329
26.5    61.5    2.99545388460639
26.5    61.625  3.03139287444911
26.5    61.75   3.06733186429182
26.5    61.875  3.10327085413453
26.5    62  3.13920984397725
26.5    62.125  3.17494109399428
26.5    62.25   3.21088008383699
26.5    62.375  3.21773549808444
26.5    62.5    3.2245909123319
26.5    62.625  3.23144632657935
26.5    62.75   3.23830174082681
26.5    62.875  3.24494941524858
26.5    63  3.25180482949603
26.5    63.125  3.24391071612018
26.5    63.25   3.23622434257
26.5    63.375  3.22833022919415
26.5    63.5    3.22064385564397
26.5    63.625  3.21254200244243
26.5    63.75   3.20485562889226
26.5    63.875  3.16704698061842
26.5    64  3.12903059251891
26.5    64.125  3.09122194424507
26.5    64.25   3.05341329597123
26.5    64.375  3.01539690787172
26.5    64.5    2.97758825959788
26.5    64.625  2.92918488021434
26.5    64.75   2.8807815008308
26.5    64.875  2.83258586127295
26.5    65  2.78418248188941
26.5    65.125  2.73577910250587
26.5    65.25   2.68737572312233
26.5    65.375  2.68467510538849
26.5    65.5    2.68176674782896
26.5    65.625  2.67885839026943
26.5    65.75   2.67595003270991
26.5    65.875  2.67304167515038
26.5    66  2.67034105741654
26.5    66.125  2.65455283066482
26.5    66.25   2.63876460391311
26.5    66.375  2.62318411698708
26.5    66.5    2.60739589023537
26.5    66.625  2.59160766348366
26.5    66.75   2.57602717655763
26.5    66.875  2.54091914601763
26.5    67  2.50601885530332
26.5    67.125  2.47111856458901
26.5    67.25   2.4362182738747
26.5    67.375  2.40131798316039
26.5    67.5    2.36641769244608
26.5    67.625  2.38989229274797
26.5    67.75   2.41357463287554
26.5    67.875  2.43704923317742
26.5    68  2.46052383347931
26.5    68.125  2.4839984337812
26.5    68.25   2.50768077390877
26.5    68.375  2.5826748509794
26.5    68.5    2.65787666787571
26.5    68.625  2.73287074494634
26.5    68.75   2.80786482201697
26.5    68.875  2.88306663891329
26.5    69  2.9582684558096
26.5    69.125  3.03347027270591
26.5    69.25   3.10867208960222
26.5    69.375  3.18408164632422
26.5    69.5    3.25928346322053
26.5    69.625  3.33448528011684
26.5    69.75   3.40989483683883
26.5    69.875  3.4038703818941
26.5    70  3.39784592694937
26.5    70.125  3.39202921183032
26.5    70.25   3.38600475688559
26.5    70.375  3.38018804176653
26.5    70.5    3.3741635868218
26.5    70.625  3.34611871035495
26.5    70.75   3.31786609406241
26.5    70.875  3.28961347776987
26.5    71  3.26136086147733
26.5    71.125  3.23331598501048
26.5    71.25   3.20506336871794
26.5    71.375  3.17639527277404
26.5    71.5    3.14793491665582
26.5    71.625  3.11926682071193
26.5    71.75   3.09080646459371
26.5    71.875  3.06213836864981
26.5    72  3.03347027270591
26.5    72.125  2.99670032356048
26.5    72.25   2.95993037441504
26.5    72.375  2.92316042526961
26.5    72.5    2.88618273629849
26.5    72.625  2.84941278715306
26.5    72.75   2.81243509818194
26.5    72.875  2.74762027256965
26.5    73  2.68259770713168
26.5    73.125  2.61757514169371
26.5    73.25   2.55276031608142
26.5    73.375  2.48773775064345
26.5    73.5    2.42271518520548
26.5    73.625  2.41315915322418
26.5    73.75   2.4033953814172
26.5    73.875  2.3938393494359
26.5    74  2.38407557762892
26.5    74.125  2.37431180582194
26.5    74.25   2.36454803401496
26.5    74.375  2.3863607157114
26.5    74.5    2.40796565758217
26.5    74.625  2.42957059945293
26.5    74.75   2.45138328114937
26.5    74.875  2.47319596284582
26.5    75  2.49480090471658
26.5    75.125  2.47568884075398
26.5    75.25   2.45657677679138
26.5    75.375  2.43767245265446
26.5    75.5    2.41856038869187
26.5    75.625  2.39944832472927
26.5    75.75   2.38033626076667
26.5    75.875  2.40214894246311
26.5    76  2.42396162415956
26.5    76.125  2.44556656603032
26.5    76.25   2.46758698755245
26.5    76.375  2.48919192942321
26.5    76.5    2.51100461111965
26.5    76.625  2.54985195852189
26.5    76.75   2.58869930592413
26.5    76.875  2.62754665332637
26.5    77  2.66639400072861
26.5    77.125  2.70524134813085
26.5    77.25   2.74388095570741
26.5    77.375  2.72663855017593
26.5    77.5    2.70918840481877
26.5    77.625  2.69173825946162
26.5    77.75   2.67428811410446
26.5    77.875  2.65704570857299
26.5    78  2.63959556321583
26.5    78.125  2.59700889895135
26.5    78.25   2.55462997451254
26.5    78.375  2.51183557042238
26.5    78.5    2.46945664598357
26.5    78.625  2.42686998171908
26.5    78.75   2.3842833174546
26.5    78.875  2.39757866629814
26.5    79  2.41087401514169
26.5    79.125  2.42416936398524
26.5    79.25   2.43746471282878
26.5    79.375  2.45076006167233
26.5    79.5    2.46405541051588
26.5    79.625  2.49646282332202
26.5    79.75   2.52907797595385
26.5    79.875  2.56169312858568
26.5    80  2.5943082812175
26.5    80.125  2.62692343384933
26.5    80.25   2.65953858648115
26.5    80.375  2.6803125690492
26.5    80.5    2.70108655161724
26.5    80.625  2.72186053418528
26.5    80.75   2.74242677692764
26.5    80.875  2.76320075949568
26.5    81  2.78397474206373
26.5    81.125  2.78875275805438
26.5    81.25   2.79373851387071
26.5    81.375  2.79851652986136
26.5    81.5    2.80329454585201
26.5    81.625  2.80828030166834
26.5    81.75   2.81305831765899
26.5    81.875  2.82157565051188
26.5    82  2.83009298336478
26.5    82.125  2.83861031621768
26.5    82.25   2.84733538889625
26.5    82.375  2.85585272174915
26.5    82.5    2.86437005460205
26.5    82.625  2.86623971303317
26.5    82.75   2.86831711128998
26.5    82.875  2.8701867697211
26.5    83  2.87205642815222
26.5    83.125  2.87413382640903
26.5    83.25   2.87600348484015
26.5    83.375  2.8288465444107
26.5    83.5    2.78148186415556
26.5    83.625  2.73432492372611
26.5    83.75   2.68716798329665
26.5    83.875  2.63980330304151
26.5    84  2.59264636261206
26.5    84.125  2.52887023612817
26.5    84.25   2.4648863698186
26.5    84.375  2.40111024333471
26.5    84.5    2.33733411685082
26.5    84.625  2.27355799036693
26.5    84.75   2.20978186388304
26.5    84.875  2.1794518493337
26.5    85  2.14912183478436
26.5    85.125  2.11879182023502
26.5    85.25   2.08866954551136
26.5    85.375  2.05833953096202
26.5    85.5    2.02800951641268
26.5    85.625  2.00391169663375
26.5    85.75   1.97981387685482
26.5    85.875  1.95571605707589
26.5    86  1.93141049747128
26.5    86.125  1.90731267769235
26.5    86.25   1.88321485791342
26.5    86.375  1.82567092619995
26.5    86.5    1.76812699448647
26.5    86.625  1.71058306277299
26.5    86.75   1.6532468708852
26.5    86.875  1.59549519934604
26.5    87  1.53795126763256
26.5    87.125  1.46337267021329
26.5    87.25   1.38879407279402
26.5    87.375  1.31421547537475
26.5    87.5    1.23963687795548
26.5    87.625  1.16485054071053
26.5    87.75   1.09027194329126
26.5    87.875  1.05911096943919
26.5    88  1.02794999558713
26.5    88.125  0.996996761560749
26.5    88.25   0.965835787708685
26.5    88.375  0.934882553682303
26.5    88.5    0.90372157983024
```

My code is:

```
library(rgeos)
set1sp <- SpatialPoints(df1)
set2sp <- SpatialPoints(df2)
df1$nearest_in_wind1 <- apply(gDistance(set1sp, set2sp, byid = TRUE), 1,  which.min)
```

But not able to put the `wind` data from `df2` to in `df1` file.

Comment: Are you aware of that `df2` is ranked along two straight lines?

Comment: thanks for the reply. How did you plot `df1` data and `df2` is basically gridded over the whole Indian region. I just put here just sample point.

Comment: I used QGIS (`Layer > Add Layer > Add Delimited Text Layer`). I selected WGS 84 as coordinate system. I don't know how but you can use R to plot points, at first you have to specify coordinate system for data.frame.

Comment: The question I've just flagged as a possible duplicate handles the "find the nearest neighbour" part of your question. If you have questions about spatial data handling then you should ask a more directed question.

Comment: @Spacedman  I already applied that code but did not work for me. That's why I posted here again.

Answer (score 0):

Package `spatstat` has a method that could work.

```
library(sf)
library(spatstat)
```

I copied your data into notepad++ and made csvs, then read them in as dataframes.

```
df1 <- read.csv('C:/data/df1.csv')
df1$ID <- seq.int(nrow(df1))
df2 <- read.csv('C:/data/df2.csv')
df2$ID <- seq.int(nrow(df2))
```

Then I cast them into `sf` spatial objects (assuming your coords are WGS84).

```
df1 <- st_as_sf(df1, coords = c('lon', 'lat'), remove = FALSE, crs = 4326)
df1 <- st_transform(df1, 32644)
df2 <- st_as_sf(df2, coords = c('lon', 'lat'), remove = FALSE, crs = 4326)
df2 <- st_transform(df2, 32644)
```

`spatstat`, as far as I'm aware, assumes planar coordinates, so I've also reprojected your data into the UTM zone that covers (most of) it. A better option would be a distance-preserving projection that covers your entire area of interest, but I'm not familiar with Indian CRS's.

Below this is a quick function to cast `sf` point dataframes to the `ppp` object that `spatstat` requires.

```
st_as_ppp <- function(x = NULL) {
  ecks <- sapply(seq.int(length(x$geometry)), function(y) {
    x$geometry[[y]][1]
    })
  why <- sapply(seq.int(length(x$geometry)), function(y) {
    x$geometry[[y]][2]
    })
  o_win <- spatstat::owin(range(ecks), range(why))
  spatstat::ppp(ecks, why, window = o_win)
}
```

Now I can cast the sf objects to ppp objects

```
df1_ppp <- st_as_ppp(df1)
df2_ppp <- st_as_ppp(df2)
```

and  get nearest neighbour using `spatstat::nncross`

```
df1_nnwind <- nncross(df1_ppp, df2_ppp)
```

The column 'which' in `df1_nnwind` contains the row number of the nearest point in `df2`, which I can use as an index to append the appropriate wind data to `df1`:

```
df1$wind <- df2$wind[c(df1_nnwind$which)]
```

Test with a quick plot:

```
plot(df1['wind'], reset = FALSE, pch = 19)
plot(df2['wind'], add = T, pch = 19)
```

Or you can write df1 and df2 to shp or gpkg and view in QGIS.

Comment: thanks for the reply. what exactly the mean `crs = 4326` and `32644`  My original file `df1` has `3520` entries and `df2` has `103043` entries. So what should I add there?

Comment: Here, read this https://github.com/datacarpentry/organization-geospatial/blob/master/_episodes_rmd/03-crs.Rmd and then this https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/spatial-class.html#crs-intro.